# How do I print a 2D array of char[][]?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, char

I made 2 dimensional array of `char[][]`. I want to print small letter by using ASCII code.
I wrote the code, but I don't have the expected results. Where I'm wrong?

I know if I fix code like answercode it works well. But I want to know why nothing happens when I use my code, even if there are no `a` in console.

Here is my code:

```java
package array;

public class Alphabet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] alphabets = new char[13][2];
        alphabets[0][0] = 'a';
        for (int i = 0; i < alphabets.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < alphabets[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(alphabets[i][j]);
                alphabets[i][j]++;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The expected output is:

```
a b
c d
e f
...
...
y z
```

Comment: Your code prints 'a' for me.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: i uploaded my expected output

Comment: and i can't see any output

Comment: What makes you think that it should print a,b,..z range? From where it should take those values? What makes you think that those values are there?

Comment: Why is an alphabet a 2 dimensional array?

Comment: You initialise them all as character 0.  And set the (0,0)th entry to a.  You iterate over them, printing the character, and _then_ incrementing it.  So (0,0) will be 'b' (but print 'a'), and all the rest will be character 1 (not '1', but the char with value 1) and print character 0 (again, not '0').

Comment: Oh i find there is an 'a' on the console. It was hiding upside . Now i have second question. why my code dose not work???   Everyone Thankyou

Comment: I answered that above.

Comment: What do you think `alphabets[i][j]++;` does?

Comment: Oh I understand Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works perfectly, but you can't see the alphabet because you haven't put all the `char` in the `char[][]`.

So, you can create a simple method called *populate*, like this:

```java
private static void populate(char[][] alphabets) {
    char c = 'a';
    for (int i = 0; i < alphabets.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < alphabets[i].length; j++) {
            if (c <= 'z') { //we want from 'a' to 'z'
                alphabets[i][j] = c;
                c++; //get the next letter
            }//if
        }//for
    }//for
}//populate
```

You can call this method instead of `alphabets[0][0] = 'a';`. So the Main code will be:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Create char[][]
    char[][] alphabets = new char[13][2];

    //populate char[][]
    populate(alphabets);

    //print the output
    for (int i = 0; i < alphabets.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < alphabets[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(alphabets[i][j]);
            alphabets[i][j]++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This is the output (I've tested it on [jdoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/)):

[image: output]